# Index variable does not incremenet at array shifting

Tags: c

I want to shift the elements of a 2D array by n-elements to the right. My array has 26 Elements. 
This doens't seem to work, and I don't know why.

```
i = 2;
c = 0;
for (i; i < 26; i++)
{
  array[1][i-1] = array[1][c];
  c++;
}
```

But I am overwriting every Element at Index i with the element of the array[0][0] and not with the next elemetn.

The indexvariable c doesn't seem to increment and I don't really know why.

Thankfull for any input.

Comment: This is an excellent moment to learn to use a debugger to see what is going on.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and provide a [mcve].

Comment: and no, you're not overwriting with the element of `array[0][0]` but `array[1][0]`... that's what your loop does.

Comment: You should add more information about the purpose. You could modify the pointer to the first element instead of checking and shifting the whole "2D array".

Comment: @Jose unless it's *not* a pointer, and rather an actual array (or in this case, an actual array of arrays). Regardless, this algorithm is dreadful. It looks like pure guessing rather than drawing up some boxes and arrows on a scratch pad, then writing the code to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a piece of paper and write down what happens step by step.

Like:

```
i = 2;
c = 0;
array[1][1] = array[1][0];
c=1;
i=3;
array[1][2] = array[1][1];
c=2;
i=4;
array[1][3] = array[1][2];
. . .
```

As you can see you start by assigning value of element 0 to element 1, then you assign value of element 1 to element 2. Since the value of element 1 is the same as value of element 0, element 2 now holds the same value as element 0 and element 1. So in the end, you actually assigns the value of element 0 to all other elements.

The solution is to start from the other end. That is:

```
array[1][25] = array[1][24];
array[1][24] = array[1][23];
array[1][23] = array[1][22];
. . .
```